# "Contro il" o "Contro al"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> Essere contro alla / la pena di morte.
>
> La palla sbatte contro il / al muro.

Sono entrambe corrette? Quale forma devo preferire in un tema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/contro-a-o-contro-di-contro_(La_grammatica_italiana)/), sono entrambe corrette, tuttavia "contro a" è raramente utilizzata nel linguaggio attuale:

> La preposizione impropria contro si può trovare prima di un nome o
>   prima di un pronome personale. Prima di un nome, lo precede
>   direttamente: "Si scagliò contro il nemico". Oppure, secondo un uso oggi
>   molto più raro (ma non scorretto), può essere seguita dalla
>   preposizione *a*: "Si scagliò contro al nemico"